# IE 8.0 Same version 2 pcs, Javascript fault only happening on 1? Is it the .js or not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8, knockout.js

2 Machines, Both XP, both on IE 8.0.6001.187, but only 1 gets this error?

I'm getting a js error 'length is not defined' in this code:

```
return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.clinicianList, function (t) {
    t.Id == code;
});
```

I tracked it down to the fact that the viewmodel

```
var locationViewModel = {
clinicianList: clinicians
...etc
};
```

which passes in the original array to knockout bindings from the controller returns a null object from this line:

```
var clinicians = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ReportTo));
```

But as I said. Only on a specific XP with a specific IE version(???). I've rewritten the .js in several ways till I found it was the line above getting a null object from the controller. 'var clinicians' is null when this happens.

So is it something local to that XP machine? What could that be? a Cache I don't know about?

Someone's got an idea right?

(I tested it on the machine with the problem on IE 7 (worked) & FF (worked) !)

Thanks

Comment: I ran into a similar type of problem.  There was one internal site I was on and had errors.  No one else did.  The only way Tech Support could fix the issues was to do a complete reformat and rebuild of my machine.  Then, the site ran without any problems.  Not pretty, but worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the differences in the compatibility view settings in the browser on both the systems?